# spotfire summary table color

Tags: color-scheme, spotfire

In Spotfire 6.5.2, is it possible to color a column heading in a summary table? I know how to color values in a regular table but can't find a way to do so in a summary table.

Thank you,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I do not see such option available without any customizations.